# Кто может объяснить смысл цикла While True в Python?

Tags: python, while

Как можно понять что значит While **True**: ... ? Я только понял, что цикл будет в таком случае бесконечным до тех пор, пока я не пропишу команду break, но в чём смысл самого выражения While **True**? И есть ли выход из такого цикла без break, например если "что-то" станет **False** :D

Может вопрос тупой, но спасибо тому, кто ответит :D

Comment: What does “while True” mean in Python?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754620/what-does-while-true-mean-in-python

Comment: Спасибо! 123123

Comment: Вроде как в питон циклы без условия не завезли, соответственно когда такой цикл необходим, то приходится использовать цикл с константой `True` в качестве условия.

Comment: Выход из такого цикла возможен при исключении, при завершении нити или процесса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Типичная ситуация для использования подобного цикла, это когда условие завершения становится известно только в середине итерации.

Например, наша программа должна считывать с консоли числа, и вычислять их произведение, до тех пор, пока не будет введен `0`

```py
total = 1

while True:
    x = int(input())

    if x == 0:
        break

    total *= x

print(total)
```

Конечно можно вынести первый ввод за пределы цикла, проверку завершения перенести в заголовок цикла.

```py
total = 1
x = int(input())

while x != 0:
    total *= x
    x = int(input())

print(total)
```

Но в таком случае программа перестает удовлетворять т.н. принципу [DRY](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%E2%80%99t_repeat_yourself).

В python 3.8 появилась новая конструкция, которая позволит избавиться от `while True` в подобных случаях

```
total = 1

while (x := int(input())) != 0:
    total *= x

print(total)
```

Но идеальным решением это тоже не назовешь, да и в обиход оно войдет только через год-два, когда большинство систем будет использовать 3.8.

Кроме того, не стоит забывать о том, что некоторые циклы могут быть безусловно бесконечными, и в таких случаях без `while True` не обойтись

```
def count(x):
    while True:
        yield x
        x += 1


for z in count(1):
    for y in range(1, z + 1):
        for x in range(1, y + 1):
            if x**2 + y**2 == z**2:
                print(f'{x}**2 + {y}**2 == {z}**2')
```

Answer (score 1):

Это означает что цикл является постоянно истинной. То есть пока правда==правда выполнять.
Можно без брейка, но тогда вместо True надо будет использовать булевую переменную которая будет равна истине. Например:

```
a = True
while a:
  #Цикл
   a = False
```

(Отвечаю с телефона, сорян)

Comment: Понял, прошёл ещё по ссылке комментария на мой вопрос. Получается из такого цикла без break выхода нет :)

Comment: Ну да, выхода нет. Рад что помог

Comment: @Ycea есть старое, но рабочее приложение StackExchange: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin

Comment: Что-то не открылось

Answer (score 0):

Гениально ответил человек по ссылке: это то же самое, что сказать While (6>5), что по сути While True и есть. Бесконечный цикл, ибо правда всегда правда :D
Там каждая строчка ответа очень интересная и понятная поэтому прикреплю его ответ сюда, чтобы прочитали потом те, кому интересно:

> Everything inside the () of the while statement is going to be
> evaluated as a boolean. Meaning it gets converted into either true or
> false.
>
> Consider in the statement while(6 > 5)
>
> It first evaluates the expression 6 > 5 which is true so is the same
> as saying while(true)
>
> Anything that is not FALSE, 0, an emptry string "", null, or undefined
> is likely to be evaluated to true.
>
> When I first started programming I used to do things like if(foo ==
> true), I didn't realise that was virtually the same thing as if(foo).
>
> So when you say while(true) its like are saying while(true == true)
>
> So to answer you question: While TRUE is True.